# What can the zeros of Laplace Transform tell to us?

Tags: roots, laplace-transform

Suppose that I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the LT is $F$.

I'd like to know if there is some solution to $f(x)=0$. I know the solutions of $F(s)=0$. Can I obtain some information for the zeros' existence for $f$?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about the zeroes, but the poles and branch points of the LT $F$ tell us an enormous amount about the original function $f$.